# What's a clean way to sharing common markup among partials in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

Assume I have a an image viewer partial, the image viewer is shown to both visitors and admins. Admins should have additional buttons to remove/edit images, while everything else remains the same for both visitors and admins. What's a clean approach keep views DRY without clogging them with `if` statements everywhere?

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

`image_partial.html.haml`:

```
.image
  %img
  if is_admin?
    .admin-stuff-here
```

What's the clean way to achieve the same results with separated views(for admins/visitors) without duplicating the same markup?

Answer (score 2):

If all admin functionality is nested within a single DOM element *(not spread out throughout the HTML for your `_image_partial.haml.erb` file)*, you could conditionally include some `_admin_controls.haml.erb` partial.

Maybe it makes sense to have these nested within a directory.

```
- app/views/_image_viewer
  |- viewer.haml.erb
  |- admin_control.haml.erb
```

and then within `_viewer.haml.erb`

```
.image
  %img
    = render partial "_image_viewer/admin_control" if is_admin?
```

Comment: What if it isn't? which is the case here

Comment: The code in your question suggests it does, which is why I answered on that assumption. Can you update your question with code that more accurately reflects the problem?